# How to enable multiple Server.log(s) in Azerothcore

Tags: logging, logfile, azerothcore

I want to enable multiple `Server.log` so I can see what happened with the server before it restarted. What I mean is: saving separate `Server.log` files every time the server restarts, instead of rewriting the same file.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is enabling `LogTimestamp` in the `worldserver.conf`, which will make the core save every `Server.log` file with a different datetime in the file name, so you can check what happened.

https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/worldserver/worldserver.conf.dist#L451